# this.file.dataDirectory was showing null in ionic2

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic2, html

this.file.dataDirectory was showing null, I have installed cordova in globally but still, I am not able to find any solution.where did I make a mistake?

```
download() {

    const fileTransfer: FileTransferObject = this.transfer.create();

    const url = 'http://www.example.com/file.pdf';
    fileTransfer.download(url, this.file.dataDirectory + 'file.pdf').then((entry) => {
      console.log('download complete: ' + entry.toURL());
    }, (error) => {
      // handle error
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use

```
cordova.file.dataDirectory
```

instead of

```
this.file.dataDirectory
```

Comment: How can I access Cordova? I added it to constructor but it didn't work